# Is there dedicated mining hardware available to mine cryptonote coins?

Tags: mining-hardware, cryptonote

I'm talking about hardware such as USB miners, etc. I'm asking, because I see people mine with `86kH/s` on my pool…

Comment: I've removed the bit where you ask "what the best mining hardware is", because we don't do product recommendations here as they would outdate quickly anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptoNote#Egalitarian_proof_of_work)

> CryptoNight is a proof-of-work algorithm that mixes graphics processing unit (GPU) and central processing unit (CPU) mining to create a system resistant to both application-specific integrated circuits (ASICs) and fast memory-on-chip devices.

So, there is no dedicated ASIC hardware (yet). You can currently only use CPU plus GPU (which of course counts as hardware but I assumed you meant dedicated to mining hardware like ASICs).